# Push Notification in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, push-notification

I've developed one Android App with Webview. In that when user click's a particular button in webview, a push notification message should reach to a particular user. I have searched in google a lot but not able to find a solution for this.

Can anyone help me in this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using fire-base push notification ..?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to use it through fire base only

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this?

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises, no progress